# Combine two regular expressions with a logical "and" operator

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a combined regular expression, but I don't know how to combine the two sub expressions

- I have an input string like this: 4711_001.doc
- In want to match the following: 4711.doc
- I am able to match 4711 with this expression: `[^\_\.]*`
- I am able to match .prt with this exression: `\.[^.]+`

Is there some kind of logical AND to combine the two expressions and match 4711.doc? How would the expression look like?

Comment: Replace `^([^_.]+).*(\.[^.]+)$` with `$1$2`, see https://regex101.com/r/56A0YS/1/

Comment: Not sure why everyone thinks the question is about Python :) What is your coding environment?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't realize that the question is not about Python till I read your comment. I hope Stefan J. understands Python.

Answer (score 3):

You can use groups to do it in one regular expression. Check out this code for reference:

```
import re
s = "4711_001.doc"
match = re.search(r"(.+?)_\d+(\..+)", s)
print(match.group(1) + match.group(2))
```

Output:

```
4711.doc
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to match the part you don't want:

```
_\d+
```

And replace this with `""`:

```
import re
s = "4711_001.doc"
match = re.sub(r"_\d+", "", s)
print(match)
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JBe7EI/4)

Answer (score 1):

For this example string **4711_001.doc**, using `[^_.]*` and `\.[^.]+` is quite a broad match as it can match any character except what is listed in the character class.

Perhaps you could make the pattern a bit more specific, matching digits at the start and word characters as the extension.

In the replacement use capture group 1 and 2, often denoted as `$1$2` or `\1\2`

```
(\d+)_\d+(\.\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Yx66j/1)

There is no language tagged, but if for example `\K` is supported to clear the match buffer this might also be an option (including the parts that you tried)

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
[^_.]*\K_[^._]+(?=\.[^.]+$)
```

In parts

- `[^_.]*\K` Match the part before the underscore, then forget what is matched so far
- `_[^._]+` Match the underscore, follwed by 1+ chars other than `.` and `_`
- `(?=\.[^.]+$)` A positive lookahead assertion to make sure what is at the right is a `.` followed by any char other than a `.` until the end of the string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tv14IP/1)